# Php, how to determine if a string is a time?

Tags: php

I want to detect if a string is a time (**00:18:31**). I know about `strtotime()` but it also detects "`now`" as OK, and so on. I need a real solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:-

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $yourtimeString) !== FALSE) {
  echo "it's a date";
}else{
echo "it's not a date";
}
```

Input:- 00:18:31 Output:- it's a date

Input:- now,NOW,now(),NOW() Output:-  it's not a date

Comment: You don't need a test for `!== FALSE` since `DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time)` returns an object!

Comment: Besides, condition will be failed if we give it input hours exceed 23 or mins exceed 59, which is not valid!
could you please! see my answer i handle these cases with a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The `validateTime()` function checks whether the given string is a valid time. using `DateTime` class and `createFromFormat()` static method.

---

```php
function validateTime($time, $format = 'H:i:s'){
  $t = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $time);
  return $t && $t->format($format) === $time;
}
// Returns true
echo var_dump(validateTime("00:18:31"));
echo var_dump(validateTime("23:59:59"));
echo var_dump(validateTime("00:02:30"));
// Returns false
echo var_dump(validateTime("31:18:31"));
echo var_dump(validateTime("24:00:00"));
echo var_dump(validateTime("23:60:60"));
```

**Explanation of `$t->format($format) === $time`**
is a test to check if the time is indeed a real time or not. for instance *23:59:59* is valid time but *24:00:00* is not.
We all know that *23:59:59* is the max acceptable Human time. and *24:00:00* is not. However, We can pretend it means the next day at *00:00:00*. that is what `DateTime::createFromFormat` do! when we give it a time exceed the maximum. It accept it by adding the remaining time to the next day.
For example
today is *2021-05-14 23:59:59*
and time to check if we give it to `createFromFormat` is *24:02:30* the date becomes next day *2021-05-15 00:02:30* 
We notice that `24:02:30 != 00:02:30`. So from that we can summarize that is not valid time. To be valid it must be the same!